# Facebook API which supports IOS SDK 5

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I have an iPhone app that is sending message to Facebook it is working fine with IOS SDK 4 but when trying to run on IOS SDK 5 it is not working and showing release and retain as errors.

we are also done making "Disable ARC' and FB files are compiled well, but our other project source need not be to make "Disable ARC', as its a typical iOS 5 project. If we "Disable ARC', then we have to add "release', "retain" etc. in all the sources. What is the solution for making FB compile without "Disabling ARC'. Whether it is possible or not?

How can we solve this? or send useful links to download Facebook API which runs on IOS SDK5.

Comment: if you turn ARC off, you'll get rid of those errors (and get a whole bunch of new ones :-)

Comment: @kalyan Andra have you got your solution...?

Answer (score 7):

These Errors are coming because you are embedding the non ARC Files(Facebook classes) with ARC enabled Classes(i suppose,as you mentioned the errors `retain,release`.).

I'd like to explain in short,With `Automatic Reference Counting(ARC)` enabled, the compiler will automatically insert `retain`, `release` and `autorelease` in the correct places in your program. You no longer have to worry about any of this, because the compiler does it for you.

I think that Using Facebook Classes(SDK) in `ios 5`, No need another `ios 5` compatible `Facebook SDK`.I think so,Facebook have not created `ios 5` compatible `facebook ios SDK`.
So Here For Using these Facebook Classes within the `ARC` Enabled Code(`ios 5`),You just need to disable the `ARC` for these Facebook classes(i.e we are intimating to compiler that we are going to take care the memory management for these classes(`Facebook Classes`)).

After doing that you'll never get those errors.

After Disabling the `ARC` for those Facebook Classes ,you may create Run(build)Application without error Easily.

For the Disabling the `ARC` you just need to set the `"-fno-objc-arc"` flag ,see how you'll do that.

**1)** Go to the Application Target.

**2)** Choose Build Phase.

**3)** Compile Sources->Set  `"-fno-objc-arc"` Flag for all Facebook Classes.

Now Run The Application Again.

I hope, It'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can **Disable Automatic Reference Counting** For these classes.

Do just follow the steps.You add compiler flags in **Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources.**

xcode[image: Disabling ARC]

The flag used is `-fno-objc-arc` press enter after writing it.! You have to double click on the right column of the row under **Compiler Flags**. Hope it helps Thanks :)